# Using a conditional statement to link a button press

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

The idea is that if one presses one of the buttons the labeled text is inputted in the top left entry box. My initial plan was to use an if statement when the button is pressed and then insert the text according.

However, I am not sure what syntax to use that would allow me to make this one line conditional statement that recognizes the button being pressed. Is this actually possible or do I need to make a separate function?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class GUI():

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.master = master
        master.resizable(True, True)
        master.title('Conversion Calculator')

        self.tabControl = ttk.Notebook(master)
        self.tab1 = ttk.Frame(self.tabControl)  # tab set up
        self.tabControl.add(self.tab1, text='Builder')
        self.tabControl.pack(expand=1, fill="both")        


        self.builder_entrybox = ttk.Entry(self.tab1, width=24) # entry box set up
        self.builder_entrybox.grid(column=0, row=0)

        self.builder_outputbox = ttk.Entry(self.tab1, width=24)    # output box set up
        self.builder_outputbox.grid(column=0, row=1)
        self.builder_outputbox.config(state='NORMAL')
        self.builder_outputbox.config(state='readonly')

        self.CH3_Button = ttk.Button(self.tab1, text='CH3', command=self.builder) # CH3 button
        self.CH3_Button.grid(column=1, row=0)

        self.CH2_Button = ttk.Button(self.tab1, text='CH2', command=self.builder) # CH2 button
        self.CH2_Button.grid(column=2, row=0)

        self.OH_Button = ttk.Button(self.tab1, text='OH', command=self.builder) # OH button
        self.OH_Button.grid(column=1, row=1)

        self.O_Button = ttk.Button(self.tab1, text='O', command=self.builder) # O button
        self.O_Button.grid(column=2, row=1)

        self.H_Button = ttk.Button(self.tab1, text='H', command=self.builder) # H button
        self.H_Button.grid(column=3, row=1)

        self.COOH_Button = ttk.Button(self.tab1, text='COOH', command=self.builder) # COOH button
        self.COOH_Button.grid(column=3, row=0)

class Logic(GUI):

    def builder (self): # adding button text to entry box (tab1)

            self.builder_entrybox.insert(0, 'CH3')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    test = Logic(root)
```

Comment: If what? The command only fire is the Button is pressed. What condition should prevent the text moving to the top left Entry?

Comment: I want to limit each button having a unique input into the top left entry. I thought using an if statement for each button would be a good way of doing this. Other if I just have the line in the builder function 'self.builder_entrybox.insert(0, 'CH3')' it  inputs 'CH3' from every button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would make a new function for every button:

```
class GUI():
    def __init__(self, master):
        # ...

        self.CH3_Button = ttk.Button(self.tab1, text='CH3', command=self.CH3_builder) # CH3 button
        self.CH3_Button.grid(column=1, row=0)

    def CH3_builder(self):
        self.builder_entrybox.insert('end', 'CH3')
```

Python can make functions on the fly, either with `functools.partial` (early binding) or `lambda` (late binding). Using that you could write the same thing like this:

```
from functools import partial

class GUI():
    def __init__(self, master):
        # ...

        self.CH3_Button = ttk.Button(self.tab1, text='CH3', command=partial(self.builder_entrybox.insert, 'end', 'CH3')) # CH3 button
        self.CH3_Button.grid(column=1, row=0)
```

But it would be better if you make a small subclass to handle all this for you, which makes your code very reusable and therefore neat:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

class Copa(ttk.Button):
    """A new type of Button that moves the text into a Entry when clicked"""
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        ttk.Button.__init__(self, master, command=self.builder, **kwargs)
    def builder(self):
        self.master.builder_entrybox.insert('end', self['text'])

class BuilderFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)

        self.builder_entrybox = ttk.Entry(self, width=24) # entry box set up
        self.builder_entrybox.grid(column=0, row=0)

        self.builder_outputbox = ttk.Entry(self, width=24)    # output box set up
        self.builder_outputbox.grid(column=0, row=1)
        self.builder_outputbox.config(state='NORMAL')
        self.builder_outputbox.config(state='readonly')

        self.CH3_Button = Copa(self, text='CH3') # CH3 button
        self.CH3_Button.grid(column=1, row=0)

        self.CH2_Button = Copa(self, text='CH2') # CH2 button
        self.CH2_Button.grid(column=2, row=0)

        self.OH_Button = Copa(self, text='OH') # OH button
        self.OH_Button.grid(column=1, row=1)

        self.O_Button = Copa(self, text='O') # O button
        self.O_Button.grid(column=2, row=1)

        self.H_Button = Copa(self, text='H') # H button
        self.H_Button.grid(column=3, row=1)

        self.COOH_Button = Copa(self, text='COOH') # COOH button
        self.COOH_Button.grid(column=3, row=0)

class GUI():
    def __init__(self, master):

        self.master = master
        master.resizable(True, True)
        master.title('Conversion Calculator')

        self.tabControl = ttk.Notebook(master)
        self.tab1 = BuilderFrame(self.tabControl)  # tab set up
        self.tabControl.add(self.tab1, text='Builder')
        self.tabControl.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    test = GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```